# PDF with iText - Center Align Strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I'm using the iText library for .NET to generate a PDF. I need to output a PDF with an image, which has three text strings positions centered vertically, but absolute Y positions. Each string uses a different font. I've been struggling for hours to find a way to do this, I can get the first line on Ok using SetSimpleColumn(), but further attempts have been fruitless.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this working with:

```
int y_offset = 20;
Phrase fullTitle = new Phrase("Some string", myFont);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, fullTitle, center, y_offset, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used either `iText` or `iTextSharp`, which I think you're referencing to. Despite, I have used `PDF Sharp` which offered a `MeasureString()` method. This method, given a `Font` and a string is able to measure the string from its `XGraphics` class which has the information about DPI, etc.

I guess that if you took an eye out to the equivalent class and method with `iText`, you should be able to do something, if it even exists.

I know it's not much help, but I hope to have given you some idea for a workaround.

Comment: I need it to work in Medium Trust, which unfortunately PDFSharp doesn't. :(

I just need to position the 3 text sections at specific places, centered horizontally.

Comment: Right, but have you looked for such a `MeasureString()` or an equivalence with *iText* to allow you to measure the string given the font and the string you want to center? After you got this, the rest is not much of a child play. =)

Comment: Yes, but I posted the question as I couldn't find anything.